# React app does not fire off onScroll events as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, react-hooks, vertical-scrolling

I am trying to show a specific component - a "sticky header" piece when the page displaying it, is scrolled X number of points off the top.

I tried doing this with the `useWindowScroll` hook from the `use-react` package, as well with a short fragment below:

```
  const [scrollTop, setScrollTop] = useState(0);

  function setScroll() {
    console.log('setScroll');
    setScrollTop(window.pageYOffset);
    console.log(new Date().getTime());
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    function watchScroll() {
      console.log('watchScroll');
      window.addEventListener("scroll", setScroll);
    }
    watchScroll();
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", setScroll);
    };
  });

  console.log('scroll top:', scrollTop);
```

Ideally, we probably want to have a bit of a delay before each new scroll event is processed, yet it is not my problem.

I would expect `setScroll` to get called whenever I scroll, every however many millisecond. However, this is NOT happening. In fact, I don't see it called ever.

Since it is not being called when approriate, my `const shouldShowStickyHeader = scrollTop > 1000;` is always set to `false`. Hence, my  is never shown. I want it to appear when the scroll to top distance is 1,000.

What is the problem?

I also tried version with everything inside the effects hook as:

```
  const [scrollTop, setScrollTop] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    function setScroll() {
      console.log('setScroll');
      setScrollTop(window.pageYOffset);
      console.log(new Date().getTime());
    }
    window.addEventListener("scroll", setScroll);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", setScroll);
    };
  }, [scrollTop]);
```

I don't see `setScroll` being printed in the console. What could be the problem?

I did a little test with `document.querySelectorAll("*").forEach(element => element.addEventListener("scroll", ({target}) => console.log(target, target?.id, target?.parent, target?.parent?.id)));`. There are indeed events being fired off when I scroll. See:

```
<div data-testid="vdp-scroll-container" id="vdp-scroll-container" class="jsx-1959376998 vdp-scroll-container">
...
<div data-testid="vdp-scroll-container" id="vdp-scroll-container" class="jsx-1959376998 vdp-scroll-container">
```

I tried putting listers directly on this element with:

```
document.getElementById('#vdp-scroll-container')?.addEventListener("scroll", setScroll);
    return () => {
      document.getElementById('#vdp-scroll-container')?.removeEventListener("scroll", setScroll);
    };
```

Still, I don't see anything getting fired off.

The styles on this `<div/>` are below:

```
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

Am I not getting anything because of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass an empty array to useEffect as the second argument so that the function is fired only after the component mounts for the first time. Not passing a second argument, will trigger the function after every rerender and passing `[scrollTop]` will trigger the function every time `scrollTop` changes.

Something like this should work:

```
  const [offset, setOffset] = React.useState(null);
  const setScroll = () => {
    setOffset(window.scrollY);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", setScroll);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", setScroll);
    };
  }, []);
```

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-cdn-ll6es?file=/src/App.js

Comment: My second version passes scrollTop already, instead of an empty array.

Comment: @IgorShmukler When you pass scrollTop to useEffect, the function you pass to useEffect will be called every time scrollTop changes. So, nearly every time the scroll event is dispatched, you are adding and then removing the event listener.

Comment: makes sense. i think that you are maybe right. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Attaching the listener to window did not work. However, after I removed `height: 100%`, I was able to subscribe to the scroll event with:

```
  const [scrollTop, setScrollTop] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const setScroll = () => {
      setScrollTop(window.pageYOffset);
    };
    document.querySelector('#vdp-scroll-container')?.addEventListener("scroll", setScroll);
    return () => {
      document.querySelector('#vdp-scroll-container')?.removeEventListener("scroll", setScroll);
    };
  }, [scrollTop]);
```